# Git - Could not find a matching version of package in magento

Tags: git, composer-php, magento2

I'm trying to install a module from github using composer, but every time I'm getting same error,

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG.
   Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package i
  s available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).
```

Below is my part of composer.json,

```
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "Worldpay-Worldpay-Magento2-CG": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG.git"
        }
    },
```

Below are the command list I have tried,

```
composer require Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG dev-master
composer require Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG:~2.0
composer require Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG @master
composer require Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG @dev-master
composer require Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG "^2.0"
composer require Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG:dev/master
```

(small letter)

```
composer require worldpay/worldpay-magento2-cg:dev-master
```

I have tried with ssh link also in composer.json. And with out `"minimum-stability": "dev",` part.

The current latest version of this module is `2.0.` And the stable branch is `Master`. I have tried to get directly that version and the branch with above commands. But every time I'm getting same error message.

And additionally latest version (2.0) of that module is not listed in **packagist**

https://packagist.org/packages/sapient/module-worldpay

In **packagist** the latest version is showing as `1.5.3`. After that I have done 4 releases. But it is not available in **packagist**. Should I submit manually ?.

So seems like somewhere I did mistake. Should I create Stable (branch name) branch in github ?. Any advise will be really great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `composer require` command you should use package name defined in `composer.json`, URL of repository is irrelevant. So it should be something like:

```
composer require sapient/module-worldpay:dev-master
```

> And additionally latest version (2.0) of that module is not listed in packagist

You should probably configure GitHub hooks to inform Packagist about repo updates, see https://packagist.org/about#how-to-update-packages

Answer (score 6):

These 2 things worked for me

I needed to add the repository reference to my composer.json because it wasn't there

```
"repositories": [
         {
             "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
```

I needed to rename my auth.json.sample to auth.json and add the public and private keys to the json.

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
 }
```

If you want to input your private and public keys manually then do not include the auth.json

[image lien](https://prnt.sc/st4iga)
As shown here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243524/could-not-find-a-matching-version-of-package-magento-product-community-edition/293614#293614